# UseEffect updating my delete 1 behind but my add works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErahL.jpg

Hi! I'm am able to input data and click Save and the card will update and show immediately. However, on clicking Delete on a card, it deletes 1 behind. For example, I click Delete on Card 2, it will correctly delete the data from the API which I am using, but on the React application/DOM, I will have to click Delete on it again or Delete on a different card for it to delete. And it continues on like that, it deletes the last card I tried to delete for the current delete... if that makes sense.

My main app js:

```
   const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
   const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

   useEffect(() => {
      //Load cities from the API - re-render when count is updated
      async function fetchData() {
         try {
            await cityCtrl.loadCities()
            setLoaded(true)
         } catch (e) {
            userMsg('Turn on the server')
         }
      }
      fetchData();
   }, [count]);

   async function onSave(city) {
      await cityCtrl.addOrUpdate(city)
      setCount(count + 1)
   }

   async function deleteCard(thekey) {
      await cityCtrl.deleteCard(thekey)
      setCount(count + 1)
   }
```

My Create Card component:

```
function CityForm(props) {
   const classes = useStyles();
   const city = props.city;
   const [errorName, setErrorName] = useState(false)
   const [errorLat, setErrorLat] = useState(false)
   const [errorLong, setErrorLong] = useState(false)
   const [errorPop, setErrorPop] = useState(false)

   function focusElement(name) {
      const el = document.querySelector(`[name=${name}]`);
      el.focus();
      el.select();
   }

   function onSave(e) {
      const cityToSave = {}
      cityToSave.key = city.key
      const idCityForm = document.getElementById('form')
      const inputs = idCityForm.getElementsByTagName('input')

      for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
         cityToSave[inputs[i].name] = inputs[i].value;
      }

      try {
         if (!cityToSave.name) {
            focusElement('name');
            setErrorName(true)
            throw new Error('*Please enter a city name');
         }
         if (cityToSave.name) {
            setErrorName(false)
         }
         if (cityToSave.population === '') {
            focusElement('population');
            setErrorPop(true)
            throw new Error('*Population cannot be blank');
         }
         if (cityToSave.population) {
            setErrorPop(false)
         }
         if (!cityToSave.latitude) {
            focusElement('latitude');
            setErrorLat(true)
            throw new Error('*Please enter the latitude');
         }
         if (cityToSave.latitude) {
            setErrorLat(false)
         }
         if (!cityToSave.longitude) {
            focusElement('longitude');
            setErrorLong(true)
            throw new Error('*Please enter the longitude');
         }
         if (cityToSave.longitude) {
            setErrorLong(false)
         }
         props.save(cityToSave);
         props.userMsg(`Saved ${cityToSave.name}`);
      } catch (e) {
         props.userMsg(e.message, "error");
      }
      e.preventDefault();
   }

   return (
      <form id='form' className={classes.root}>
         <Grid>
            <Typography variant='h5' component="h2" className={classes.item}>
               Create a City
            </Typography>
            <Typography className={classes.msg} id='addMsg'>
               {props.message}
            </Typography>
            <TextField name='name' label='City Name:' className={classes.item}
               error={errorName} inputProps={{ style: { textAlign: 'center' } }}
               defaultValue={city.name} />
            <TextField name='population' label='Population:' type='number' className={classes.item}
               error={errorPop} inputProps={{ style: { textAlign: 'center' } }}
               defaultValue={city.population} />
            <br></br>
            <TextField name='latitude' label='Latitude:' type='number' className={classes.item}
               error={errorLat} inputProps={{ style: { textAlign: 'center' } }}
               defaultValue={city.latitude} />
            <TextField name='longitude' label='Longitude:' type='number' className={classes.item}
               error={errorLong} inputProps={{ style: { textAlign: 'center' } }}
               defaultValue={city.longitude} />
            <br></br>
            <Button
               className={classes.btnPadding}
               variant="contained"
               color="primary"
               size="large"
               startIcon={<SaveIcon />}
               onClick={onSave}
            >Save</Button>
         </Grid>
      </form>
   )
}
```

Cards Component where I handle delete:

```
function CityCards(props) {
   const classes = useStyles();
   let cards;
   if (props.cities) {
      cards = Object.keys(props.cities).map(k => {
         const p = props.cities[k];
         return (
            <Card className={classes.card}
               key={p.key} mykey={p.key} >
               <CardContent style={{ paddingBottom: 0 }} className={classes.cardContent}>
                  <List className={classes.list}>
                     <Typography variant='h5' className={classes.cardHeader}>
                        {p.name}
                     </Typography>
                     <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
                        <img className={classes.img} src={latSvg} alt='latitude'></img>
                        <ListItemText className={classes.listText}
                           primary='Latitude:'
                           secondary={
                              <Typography variant="subtitle2">
                                 {p.latitude}
                              </Typography>
                           } />
                     </ListItem>
                     <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
                        <img className={classes.img} src={longSvg} alt='longitude'></img>
                        <ListItemText className={classes.listText}
                           primary='Longitude:'
                           secondary={
                              <Typography variant="subtitle2">
                                 {p.longitude}
                              </Typography>
                           } />
                     </ListItem>
                     <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
                        <img className={classes.img} src={popSvg} alt='people'></img>
                        <ListItemText className={classes.listText}
                           primary='Population:'
                           secondary={
                              <Typography variant="subtitle2">
                                 {p.population}
                              </Typography>
                           } />
                     </ListItem>
                  </List>
                  <List className={classes.list}>
                     <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
                        <ListItemText className={classes.listText}
                           primary='How Big? '
                           secondary={props.cityCtrl.howBig(p.population)}></ListItemText>
                     </ListItem>
                     <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
                        <ListItemText className={classes.listText}
                           primary='Which Sphere? '
                           secondary={props.cityCtrl.whichSphere(p.latitude)}></ListItemText>
                     </ListItem>
                  </List>
                  <List className={classes.list}>
                     <ListItem className={classes.listItemInput} >
                        <TextField label='#' type='number' inputProps={{ style: { textAlign: 'center' } }} />
                     </ListItem>
                  </List>
                  <CardActions className={classes.buttonArea}>
                     <Button variant="outlined" color="primary">Moved In</Button>
                     <Button variant="outlined" color="primary">Moved Out</Button>
                     <Button variant="outlined" color="secondary" onClick={deleteCity}>Delete</Button>
                  </CardActions>
               </CardContent>
            </Card >
         )
      });
   }

   function deleteCity(e) {
      let thekey = e.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('mykey')
      props.deleteCard(thekey)
      props.userMsg('Deleted city')
   }

   return (
      <Grid className={classes.root}>
         {cards}
      </Grid>
   )
}
```

My delete function that works, it deletes the city object from the API:

```
    async deleteCard(thekey) {
        let theUrl;
        if (thekey) {
            theUrl = url + 'delete'
        }
        await postData(theUrl, { key: Number(thekey) });
    }
```

I'm pretty new to React and this is my first time using UseEffect - from my understanding, I have made 'count' state to update each time something is added or deleted so I could put 'count' into the dependency array bracket in the UseEffect so that the UseEffect can re-render when it notices it has changed. It works great with my onSave function, but not for the deleteCard function even though their the same... any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: can you add the html from where your save and delete functions are called? i can't really see nothing wrong with the code you presented

Comment: @Japsz Here it is, sorry.

Comment: So, just a sanity check but you've tested `cityCtrl.deleteCard()` actually resolves, right?

Comment: @dx-over-dt Yes, it works and does what it should, I've added that code to my post. I just seem to be having a rendering problem.